# JEditorPane - In what order are edit events called?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, document, jeditorpane

Let's say you have a JEditorPane with which you have registered both an UndoableEditListener and a DocumentListener. When you change the underlying document's contents by typing in the editor pane, what is the order in which the events are fired?

In addition, I assume that, in the interest of efficiency, calling either of these methods:

- UndoableEdit.undo()
- UndoableEdit.redo()

...will not trigger a new UndoableEdit event, but will still trigger a new DocumentEvent.  Can anyone confirm whether this is indeed the case?

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing Undo and Redo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#undo). Then you can download the TextComponentDemo example, add a few println() statements to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying what camickr suggested, it seems that this is the order of events:

1. When typing in the editor pane (including cutting, copying and pasting) or changing the document font/style, the document will fire a DocumentEvent before it fires an UndoableEditEvent.
2. When calling UndoableEdit.undo() or UndoableEdit.redo(), only a corresponding DocumentEvent will be fired.

Comment: beware: if undocumented, the sequence is an implementation detail, that is might change without notice and should not be relied on. Curious: why do you need it?